# Box-Muller Method

Tags: uniform-distribution, random, chi-squared

How can I extend the Box-Muller Method to the n-dimensional case and use it to devise a method of generating n iid standard normal random samples (n ≥ 3) when chi-square and uniform random samples are given?

Comment: Generate $n/2$ pairs with the basic algorithm. No need to involve chi-square.

Comment: @LutzLehmann since the basic algorithm is 
1. Generate random numbers U1 and U2
2. Compute X1 and X2, so to generate n iid standard normal random samples, shouldn't we generate U1, U2 ,..... Un? and then compute X1, X2,... Xn ?

Comment: FYI I referred to the algorithm on page 17 http://pages.stat.wisc.edu/~yzwang/361note1.pdf

Comment: You can just generate $U_1,U_2$ and compute $X_1,X_2$, then generate $U_3,U_4$ and compute $X_3,X_4$, and so on. The question is, do you just need the i.i.d. normal variables, or is this an exercise to use the $\chi^2$ distriution? You would need polar coordinates where the uniformly distributed angles fill the unit sphere uniformly, which is easiest in dimensions that are even or, even more, powers of $2$.